# Animation Nodes – Would they be the best method to create a similar animation?

Tags: animation, modifiers, particles, animation-nodes

Would animation Nodes be the ideal procedure to create a similar animation to the gif shown.

The learning curve appears to be quite significant so if I proceed down this path I would like to be sure it's the best way to create this style of animation.[image: gif showing desired animation]

Comment: Given that they all follow similar paths, tubes like those could be done with curves, animating bevel factor start and end.

Comment: This is currently way too broad for this site, try working on it and post specific problems you encounter as questions here. It is much easier to get help if you have a starting place that you have been working from.

Comment: I have re-phrased the question – is that more appropriate?

Comment: I agree with Susu, use curve bevel and play with the Start and End values, or a mesh with array and curve modifiers, then link-duplicate the curve to create several ones, it's not as complicated as it looks in my opinion

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll give that a go!